# Objects Not Being Saved to Core Data Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am trying to add objects to a Core Data Database using the following code:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[CoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] persistentStoreCoordinator];

    Feed *feed = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Feed" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    feed.feedID = dictionary[@"feed_id"];

    feed.siteURL = dictionary[@"site_url"];

    feed.title = dictionary[@"title"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Feed is a subclass of NSManagedObject. The persistentStoreCoordinator returned from the sharedCoreDataController (a singleton) is the persistentStoreCoordinator from a UIManagedDocument (created or opened when the app launches). As far as I can tell, the document is being created or opened successfully. I am running this code in the simulator, and I'm looking in the directory in which I am saving the Database (the apps Documents directory), but the persistentStore file is not being updated to reflect the new objects being added. Am I doing something wrong? I should also point out that the above code is being executed multiple times on a concurrent, asynchronous queue.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Update:** After the suggestions from Alexander and Duncan, the code above has been updated to reflect the changes. Sadly, however, I haven't noticed any difference (the new data is not appearing in the persistentStore file).

Comment: Where are you calling save?

Comment: I would avoid creating multiple instances of the managedObjectContext if I were you.

Comment: @Paul.s I didn't realise I had to. :) I have tried adding the lines mentioned bellow by Alexander and Duncan, but sadly it doesn't appear to have worked. I was under the impression that UIManagedDocument autosaved.

Comment: do you have any errors on the console while trying to save the data? maybe you are trying to set values for attributes improperly or you do not set a required one?

Comment: @viperking no errors on the console, and none of the attributes are required.

Answer (score 1):

Have you called the line to save your `managedObjectContext`? How about this:

```
NSError *error;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[CoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] persistentStoreCoordinator];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in arrayOfData) {

    Feed *feed = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Feed" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    feed.feedID = dictionary[@"feed_id"];

    feed.siteURL = dictionary[@"site_url"];

    feed.title = dictionary[@"title"];

}

NSError *error;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

I would avoid creating a managedObjectContext for each object you insert.

Answer (score 0):

First, using `UIManagedDocument` is not recommended.  It is not intended to be your single app wide context.  It is meant for document style applications.

Second, the `NSManagedObjectContext` that is exposed from the `UIManagedDocument` doesn't have a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` attached to it.  It is a child context of a private `NSManagedObjectContext` that then has a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  I suspect that if you used the debugger you may find that your `NSManagedObjectContext` is missing its `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

In any event, you are using `UIManagedDocument` and then trying to attach another `NSManagedObjectContext` to the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  That is a bad design and you should at a minimum remove the `UIManagedDocument` or stop creating a new `NSManagedObjectContext`.

What is the point of the new context?  What are you trying to solve with this code?